# adding a line at the end of the .bat file ignoring the newline

Tags: batch-file

I have a .bat file with the following structure:

```
istruction1[newline]
```

I would like to append some parameters in a way that the resulting file is:

```
istruction1 param
```

currently i have:

```
istruction1[newline]
param
```

Basically I want to get rid of the newline...how can I do that?

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%i in (my.bat) DO echo %%i param
```

This little script will append `param` at the end of every (non empty) line in your input file (`my.bat`). You can also issue that directly from the command line, simply substituting `%%` with a single `%`:

```
for /f "delims=" %i in (my.bat) DO echo %i param
```

Comment: Note that this will strip empty lines from the file.